# How do I update a value in a table based on some date interval?

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have a Product table with a price.
I just want to update that price in a date interval.

Example:
apple is 10 
And from 2018-02-02 to 2018-03-02 I want to update the price to 12.

I mention that I create a second table PriceInterval to insert the date interval.
 `enter code here`[Pseudocode for my sqlscript](https://pastebin.com/1w2Eu6mV)

Comment: Can you provide some code you've tried ?

Comment: I would move the price to intervalprice and change from float to decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I have understood the question correctly. A possible solution to what you're describing will mean changing the schema slightly. Having a new field in the product intervals for a new price between two dates allows you still keep the default price, when the interval is over. And using a query to select the price based on the date.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_intervals;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

CREATE TABLE products (
    ID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(18,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkProductId PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE product_intervals (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ProductId INT NOT NULL,
    DateTo DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DateFrom DATETIME NOT NULL,
    NewPrice DECIMAL(18,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkProductIntervalId PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT fkProductId FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES `products`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO products (`Name`, Price)
              SELECT 'Apple', 0.10
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Banana', 0.20;

INSERT INTO product_intervals (ProductId, DateTo, DateFrom, NewPrice)
    SELECT 2, STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-10T00:00:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'), STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-15T00:00:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'), 0.30;


select p.`Name`, CASE WHEN pi.NewPrice IS NOT NULL THEN pi.NewPrice ELSE p.Price END AS Price
FROM products p
left join product_intervals pi ON p.ID = pi.ProductId AND DateFrom > NOW() AND DateTo < NOW();
```

The key part to this is the left join and the CASE statement in the select query. This code hasnt been fully tested, so it might need a bit of tweaking but hopefully will give you a good indication of what a solution could be.